# R need to make this process faster--for loop, function, or something else

Tags: r, performance, function, loops

I have a set of code, below, and I need to run it 120 times, with the variables modified, of course, for each run. I tried a for loop and I tried to create a function. I just want to do this process faster. Can someone please help me? The variables I need to have modified are score and seconds. So, it would be score1, seconds1 for the first run, score2, seconds2 for the second run, and so on. Thank you.

```
 pre <- aggregate(score~seconds, dataframe, FUN = sum)
 freqsdf <- data.frame(table(SecsOnly$seconds))
 condp <- pre$score/freqsdf$Freq
 condp <- data.frame(condp)
 par(mar = c(5,5,5,5))
 hist(dataframe$seconds, xlab = "", ylab = "", ylim = c(0, 25), axes =    FALSE, col = "grey", main = 'title here', breaks = 100)
axis(4, ylim = c(0, 25), col = "black", col.axis = "black", las = 2,   cex.axis = 1)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(pres$seconds, condp$condp, col = "red" , type = "l", xlab = "Time",   ylab = "y axis label", ylim=c(0,1.0))
abline(h = 0.20)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `apply` family of functions? e.g. `lapply`, `sapply`, etc.?

Comment: youre going to have to give more info. even using `with(dataframe, tapply(score, seconds, sum))` would be faster than aggregate

Comment: You don't want a loop, you probably want to write a function and then use one of the `apply` family members. But are seconds1, scores1, seconds2, scores2 all already in a dataframe or matrix?

Comment: Yeah, seconds1, etc... are all in a dataframe. Should I transform it into a matrix?

Comment: @rawr7, so going by what Elin said--do I have to use that code template you provided and include it in my function instead of aggregate(), and then after I create the function, do I have to use a type of apply?

Comment: @Elin, I tried this, and got an error message: > f1(dataset[["scores1"]], dataset[["seconds1"]])
Error in tapply(score, seconds, sum) : 
  object 'dataset' not found

Comment: No dataframe is good.  So what you want to do first I think is get the names of the columns so you have a vector with the list of scores- and seconds- .... or do you know already exactly how many pairs there are?

Comment: @Elin. Yeah, there are 120 scores variables and 120 seconds variables. So I have score1, score2...score120, and seconds1, seconds2...seconds120. What should I do next? Thanks

Comment: Now, after much struggle, I keep getting this error: Error in secsmatrix$score : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: I'm so lost. I thought I just had to use tapply like how rawr suggested, above. I did that, and it worked for a standalone code, for score1 and seconds1. But it doesn't work when I put the tapply/with stuff in a function. I'm not sure now what to do. Can someone please help me? This is so painful.

Comment: Well tapply you would use to call a function, though sometimes you call tapply from inside another apply.  So say you have scoreNameList and SecondsNameList that are just the respective arrays of 120 strings giving the column names.  THen you can make a function that takes those two arrays as arguments.

Comment: ok. Thanks so much, Elin! I will work on doing what you say. Thanks again!